# Breakpoints is not hitting while debugging a .NET MAUI android application

Tags: android, xamarin, breakpoints, .net-6.0, maui

I have been working on a MAUI android application and when debugging, the breakpoints is not hitting and the application enter in a break state. But for windows app it works well.
I think this is an issue with the .NET 6 Android Tooling in visual studio 2022. Is there any solutions for this problem ?

Comment: im having the same issue. ill report back if i find out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: no point is providing any code, it's just maui + vs bug

Answer (score 3):

Here is a few steps I did to make things work with debugging MAUI Android apps. I was able to debug and get my regular exceptions and hit breakpoints after this.

1. Add this code to Android platform main activity OnCreate method

   `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;`

Then this hander method in the same class

```
private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{ System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());}
```

2. Reset Your Exceptions for CLR. Shortcut is (**Ctrl+Alt+E**).

   Just double-click on the CLR Exceptions checkbox to reset.

[image]

3. Disable Debug Your Code Only in Options

[image]

Comment: I try this solution but I still having the same problem

Comment: Hi @sina, could you please provide a basic demo to github or driver so we can try to reproduce the problem on our side?

Answer (score 1):

I was also having problems debugging some projects. (Preview 17.1.0) The ones that were failing had the following project settings.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-ios;net6.0-android;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks> ...
```

Moving Android first fixed my problem

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it is now working, try this:

1. Windows -> Settings -> Update & Security -> For Developers -> Developer Mode - On
   [image]
2. Solution Properties -> Deploy - On
   [image]
3. Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Xml Hot Reaload -> Disable all
   [image]

4. The you can just set your project has startup and run it.